# Perl Comparing 2 Arrays of Arrays takes too long

Tags: perl

I've developed a comparator tool in perl, that takes data from 2 CSV files and compares them according to a set of unique keys and generates an excel report.
This tool works very well as long as i have 20k - 30k rows, with 10 columns per CSV file, but the time taken by the comparison algorithm rises too high, currently i'm running it for 98k rows in each CSV file and it's been running for over 4 hours now with some more time to go i think.

The algo i'm using is:

1. Loop the first array
2. Grep the second array using indexes identified as unique keys with data from the first array
3. Push the matched array to a new array and remove it from the original array, this way at the end i get the rows that were matched in a new array and the rows which cannot be matched stay in the original array.

Following is my comparison code:

```
# Actual comparison
# Matched rows will go to @finalMatchedArray1 and @finalMatchedArray2
# Unmatched arrays will stay in the original arrays
for ( my $j=0; $j<=$#matchArray1; $j++ ) {
    my @result = map {$_}
        grep { "@{ $matchArray2[$_] }[@mapKeyArray2]" eq "@{ $matchArray1[$j] }[@mapKeyArray1]" }
        0 .. $#matchArray2;

    if ( defined $result[0] ) {
        push @finalMatchedArray1,$matchArray1[$j];
        push @finalMatchedArray2,$matchArray2[$result[0]];
        splice ( @matchArray2,$result[0],1 );
        splice ( @matchArray1,$j,1 );
        $j--;
    }
}
```

Following is the Data:

```
$matchArray1   = [[qw(a b c)], [qw(d e f)], [qw(g h i)]];
$matchArray2   = [[qw(d e f)], [qw(g k i)], [qw(a b c)]];
$mapKeyArray1  = [1,2];
$mapKeyArray2  = [1,2];    #Can be different in real example
```

This code works perfectly fine for less than 20k rows, i need to improve its performance in case of higher volume (98k rows in each CSV in this case)

Please provide any pointers, code changes that might help me speed up the matching process.

Comment: What is the purpose of `map {$_}`? This does nothing at all, just adds another process.

Comment: I'm relatively new to perl, i thought this will give me the index of the matched array. What do you suggest?

Comment: Completely remove `map {$_}` but that wont make significant difference.

Comment: I suggest remove the map statement. You are already passing the index with `0 .. $#matchArray1`. That statement just returns the index one more time. I.e. if you have the list `1,2,3` and pass it through `map {$_}` it is still `1,2,3`. There is no function that is able to give you the index of an array element if you do not already have it.

Comment: removed, thanks for the tip, but can you suggest if there is an altogether better approach than this? i'll run the tool again and check how much the performance improved, but if you have a better solution please let me know

Comment: Your example data doesn't make sense. The `mapKeyArray` value of 3 extends beyond the maximum index of the `matchArray`, which is 2.

Comment: You might see a speed improvement if you sort your arrays beforehand. Also, if you expect only one match per element, you can gain a lot by exiting the loop early (not possible when using `grep`).

Comment: An alternative solution would be to not load all of the data into memory at once. If we assume the case of 98K rows in each file, you are loading 196K rows into memory then using a O(n^2) algorithm to compare them; the performance just wont scale well.

Comment: I have sorted the arrays before hand, forgot to mention that. that did give me some improvement but not a lot. do you think if i used a for loop and exited it upon each match it'd be faster?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen What logic should i use if i were to break my arrays?

Comment: You don't specify the comparison criterion, only an algorithm that tries to perform the comparison. What exactly do you want to report about the two files?  What exactly, besides the two files, are the arguments, two column numbers? SQL was designed for this kind of thing, aren't you just trying to perform a join?  I have a simple Perl script that can be used to run SQL queries against CSV files and I would use it for this purpose.

Comment: The data you presented is not sorted. I don't mean sort the inner arrays, I mean sort them by the comparison you make, i.e. `"a b c"` vs `"d e f"`, etc. If you use a `foreach` loop instead, you can break the loop with `last` when you find a match.

Comment: @reinierpost can you tell me about this script?

Comment: @TPL i understood what you meant by sorting, both my arrays are sorted beforehand based on one of the indexes. my bad in representing the data above.

Comment: @reinierpost what i want to do is, pick a row from CSV1, find a similar row from CSV2 based on a unique key, then report if all the other elements are matching or not. Also at the end show rows from both CSV1 and CSV2 which did not match.

Comment: @Suyash You might find that using a database is the better option here.

Comment: @ikegami no it doesn't and TLP i have various data sources, i have written several adapters to bring them all to a common platform i.e. CSV so ithat i can load them up into arrays and compare

Comment: How can you check "if all the other elements are matching or not" when they're the fields aren't in the same order in both? Your code doesn't even try to do this.

Comment: @ikeagami there exists another set of indexes that identify the which column to match from CSV1 with which in CSV2

Comment: @Syyash: so that's an OUTER JOIN in SQL. Like you, I tend to convert my data to CSV and then process it with Perl scripts. However in this case I would implement the operation in SQL. I'm happy to share my scripts.

Comment: @Syvash: If you want to do it without SQL, assuming the selected key columns are indeed unique in both files, and that both of them are sorted on the keys, you can just have a loop in which you keep the latest line read from both files in variables, read a single line from one of the two files, compare it against the lines you stored, report if there's a mismatch, and update the variable(s) as appropriate. That will be linear in the size of the files.

Comment: BTW this can also be done with Unix tools `sort` and `join`.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer, but splicing an array over which you are iterating is a giant red flag. `while (@a) { splice(@a, 0, 1); }` shifts (N-1)+(N-2)+(N-3)+...+1 elements, which is (N-1)+(N-2)+(N-3)+...+1+0 = N(N-1)/2 = O(N^2)

Comment: (Well, `splice` is optimized to be "free" when splicing from the start of the array, so you really only get O(N^2) is you skip one some elements, which is what code normally does.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're searching every element of one array for every element of the other array. That's O(N<sup>2</sup>) for something that can be done in O(N).

Generally speaking,

```
for my $ele_a (@a) {
   for my $ele_b (@b) {
      if (generate_key($ele_a) eq generate_key($ele_b)) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

can be written as

```
my %b;
for my $ele_b (@b) {
   $b{ generate_key($ele_b) } = $ele_b;
}

for my $ele_a (@a) {
   if (exists($b{generate_key($ele_b)}) {
      if (generate_key($ele_a) eq generate_key($ele_b)) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

We can apply that here.

```
my @file1_key_idxs = ...;   # Indexes of key fields.
my @file2_key_idxs = ...;   # Indexes of key fields. 

my @file1_data_idxs = ...;  # Indexes of fields to compare.
my @file2_data_idxs = ...;  # Indexes of fields to compare. 

my @matches;                # Array of [ \@keys, \@data ]
my @non_matches;            # Array of [ \@keys, \@file1_data, \@file2_data ]
my @file1_adds;             # Array of rows from file1 not in file2.
my @file2_adds;             # Array of rows from file2 not in file1.

open(my $fh1, '<:encoding(...)', ...) or die $!;
open(my $fh2, '<:encoding(...)', ...) or die $!;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1 });

my %file2;
while ( my $file2_row = $csv->getline($fh2) ) {
   my @key = @{ $file2_row }[ @file2_key_idxs ];
   my $key = pack("(N/a*)*", @key;

   $file2{$key} = $file2_row;
}
```

```
while ( my $file1_row = $csv->getline($fh1) ) {
   my @key = @{ $file1_row }[ @file1_key_idxs ];
   my $key = pack("(N/a*)*", @key);
   if (defined(my $file2_row = $file2{$key})) {
      my @file1_data = @{ $file1_row }[ @file1_data_idxs ];
      my $file1_data = pack("(N/a*)*", @file1_data);

      my @file2_data = @{ $file2_row }[ @file2_data_idxs ];
      my $file2_data = pack("(N/a*)*", @file2_data);

      if ($file1_data eq $file2_data) {
         push @matches, [ \@key, \@file1_data ];
      } else {
         push @non_matches, [ \@key, \@file1_data, \@file2_data ];
      }

      delete $file2{$key};
   } else {
      push @file1_adds, $file1_row;
   }
}

while (my $key = each(%file2)) {
    my $file2_row = delete($file2{$key});
    push @file2_adds, $file2_row;
}
```

If one of the files tends to be smaller than the other, it should be file2 to save memory and to speed things up a little.

If memory is not a concern, the last loop can be replaced with the following to speed things up a little:

```
@file2_adds = values(%file2);
```

Comment: Some of the statements can easily be combined. I was a bit verbose for documentation purposes.

Comment: I used `pack("(N/a*)*", @key)` instead of `"@key"` in case the key fields could contain spaces.

Comment: Wow! pretty damn good.. i'm implementing it right now and will get back

Answer (score 1):

Remember your time-memory tradeoff. If you can spare the memory, a hash lookup is going to be much quicker for you. C-speed as opposed to Perl-speed.

I put the second part into a while loop, because by converting it to your purposes, you can halve the load of having two large tables in memory at the same time.

However the problem that this solution poses is that "duplicate" lines in the same file would be eliminated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( @finalMatchedArray1, @finalMatchedArray2 );
my @matchArray1  = ( ["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"] );
my @matchArray2  = ( ["d","e","f"], ["g","k","i"], ["a","b","c"] );
my @mapKeyArray1 = ( 1,2 );
my @mapKeyArray2 = ( 1,2 );

my %lookup = map { ( "@{$_}[@mapKeyArray1]" => $_ ) } @matchArray1;

while ( @matchArray2 ) { 
    my $arr2 = shift @matchArray2;
    if ( my $arr1 = delete $lookup{ "@{$arr2}[@mapKeyArray2]" } ) {  
        push @finalMatchedArray1, $arr1;
        push @finalMatchedArray2, $arr2;
    }
}
```

The lack of duplicates could be handled by doing this to populate your table:

```
my %lookup;
while ( @matchArray1 ) { 
    my $i = shift @matchArray;
    push @{ $lookup{ "@{$i}[@mapKeyArray1]" } }, $i;
}
```

And then your match process would be like so:

```
while ( @matchArray2 ) { 
    if ( my $list = $lookup{ "@{$arr2}[@mapKeyArray2]" } ) { 
        if ( @$list ) { 
            push @finalMatchedArray1, shift @$list;
            push @finalMatchedArray2, $arr2;
        }
        delete $lookup{ $key } unless @$list;
    }
}
```